# i have a circuit in which some components need 5V and some need 3V.

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

should i get 3V battery and go for a buck boost or 7.4V battery and go for a voltage regulator? which is easier and better to use?

Answer (score 3):

Regulating down is simpler. If you use adjustable linear regulators you can even use the same part number for the 5V rail and the 3V rail.

Answer (score 2):

Like Daniel said, regulating down is easier. However you got a few choices to make. You can either go with linear regulators or switching regulators. With linear regulators, you might need a heat sink depending upon the current usage. If you have to use a heat sink, you are also wasting a lot of battery power. Alternative is to analyze the situation and use a switching regulator or a combination of both as outlined below:

Let's assume, you can use 7.4V lipo battery.

Estimate the current usage for 5V and 3.3V line.

If both lines are supplying low current (maybe 50mA each), you can use two linear regulators. This will save you some money as linear regulators are cheap.

7.4 --(LR)--> 5 --(LR)--> 3.3

If 5V line gives out more current(500mA) and 3.3V line gives out less current(100mA), then you can go for one switching regulator and one linear regulator.

7.4 --(SR)--> 5 --(LR)--> 3.3

If 5V line gives out less current(100mA) and 3.3V line gives out more current(500mA), then you can go for one switching regulator and one linear regulator in this arrangement.

7.4 --(LR)--> 5 and 7.4 --(SR)--> 3.3

If both lines are supplying high current, then you can go for two switching regulators. There can be two possible arrangements depending upon their current ratings and voltage difference requirement between input and output.

7.4 --(SR)--> 5 and 7.4 --(SR)--> 3.3

7.4 --(SR)--> 5 --(SR)--> 3.3